# Laravel write UnitTest for service method which contains dependencies

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Can't figure out how to write Unit test for a specific service method, which has some dependencies inside. Here is a simplified class and method I want to test.

```
class SimpleService 
{
  protected $someAuthService;

  public function __construct(SomeAuthService $someAuthService) {
    $this->someAuthService = $someAuthService;
  }

  public function getDemoData()
  {
    $demoDataDTO = new DataDTO($this->someAuthService->login($email));

    return [
      'someKey1' => $demoDataDTO->getSomeKey1(),
      'someKey2' => $demoDataDTO->getSomeKey2(),
    ];
  }
}
```

I want to test getDemoData method so I wrote test class:

```
class SimpleServiceTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testGetDemoData()
  {
    // and at this point I'm not sure what to do next. 
    // let's say I want to test if this method returns expected array
  }
}
```

Comment: you probably should have injected the DataDTO in the constructor

Comment: I can refactor, no problems, but need to know how this can help.

Comment: [Mocking Test](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking) , you can also in ur test make an instance of your service and call getDemoData() then make your assertion

Comment: I know about mocking but don’t know how to use it in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the easiest way to do it, is using a method to get the Object you need:

```
public function getDemoData()
{
   $demoDataDTO = $this->getDataDao();

   return [
     'someKey1' => $demoDataDTO->getSomeKey1(),
     'someKey2' => $demoDataDTO->getSomeKey2(),
   ];
}
public function getDataDao(){
   return new DataDTO($this->someAuthService->login($email));
}
```

and then in your test you can mock that method, so it will return a fake  `DataDTO` that you made up for your test,

Otherwise, you should separate your Service with the responsibility of creating the `DataDTO`, and so you should create a `DataDTOFactory`, pass that factory into the constructor of your Service, and use that to build your `DataDTO`.
In this way, when you are testing, you will be able to pass a "fake factory" that returns your mock object

Comment: No need to create a new method `getDataDao`, still a good practice to do so. He just needs to replace `$demoDataDTO` line with a line that will not have `new DataDTO`. That is what you did, or a simpler solution would be to just do `$demoDataDTO = app(DataDTO::class);` and let the service container instantiate the mock he will have to create on the test using `$this->app->bind(...)`

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes sure D.I. is always a great solution for this kind of problem